# Node.js connecting to signalR 2

Tags: .net, node.js, websocket, signalr

- I have a signalR hub that works fine in the traditional sense. I can connect to it through javascript/jquery and things work fine.
- I need to connect node.js as a client to signalR and I'm having some trouble. Is there an easy way to do this?

I've been trying to implement this node library: [signalr-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/signalr-client) and keep running into an issue on the node side. "Sec-WebSocket-Accept header from server didn't match expected value of {hashed value}".

When I debug the .NET hub side, I can tap into:

```
override Task OnConnected()
```

During debugging I can see the value of the request header "Sec-WebSocket-Key" coming through properly:

[image]

However the response on the node side always errors out with this:

[image]

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

open:
node-modules/websocket/lib/websocketclient.js

```
if (headers['sec-websocket-accept'] !== expectedKey) {
//this.failHandshake('Sec-WebSocket-Accept header from server didn\'t match expected value of ' + expectedKey);
//return;
}
```

remark 2 lines as above.. 
thats all